# Angular: How to create a dynamic menu in angular from database data (Web API data)?

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, angular9

I'm working with angular9. I don't have any idea of creating a dynamic menu in angular. Offcourse, I  have explored my question on internet. But, didn't get a usefull ans.

Actually I have created two tables in database (i.e MainMenu and subMenu). I have to create a web api in .net Core for that and want to bind web api data into angular [means want to create a dynamic menu angular from web api data].

Tables are as following.
[MainMenu Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGgPG.jpg)

[SubMenu Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJWDR.jpg)

Any suggestion for that? Thankyou!

Comment: Share your code.

Comment: Angular code or web api?